# Triggering a Method from another ViewController using a button in a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

The issue I am having is that I want to call a method in a navigationController by clicking a button inside a UIView (footer). When I press the button, it should call the method I'm trying to access to open the Video recorder in the code below.

I was told I could implement a delegate method or use a NSNotification. Below is what I have:

My footer (ESPhotoDetailsFooterView.m) has my button that I created. My footer only contains a UIView.

The method I'm trying to access in my footer resides in (ESTabBarController.m)

This is what I am trying to trigger when pressing my button:

```
RecorderViewController *viewController = [[RecorderViewController alloc] init];
    [viewController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self.navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self.navController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self presentViewController:self.navController animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
```

I am new to Objective C and understand the basics. I cannot figure out what I need to do to accomplish this. Any help would be much appreciated.

The code for the button is as follows:

```
// Create a standard UIButton programmatically using convenience method
    UIButton *camButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    // Set the location (x,y) and size (width,height) of the button
    camButton.frame = CGRectMake(9.0f, 8.0f, 35.0f, 35.0f);

    // Create UIImages from image resources in your application bundle
    // using convenience methods (no need to release)
    UIImage *normal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BingComm"];
    UIImage *highlighted = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BingCommClick"];

    // Set the button's background to an image
    [camButton setBackgroundImage:normal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [camButton setBackgroundImage:highlighted forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    // Add the target-action for the touch event
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wundeclared-selector"

    [camButton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.mainView addSubview:camButton];
```

Comment: How how you set up the button, in a storyboard or in code? It is unclear if the button's target, i.e. the object that is told when the button is pressed, (ideally some type of view controller) is set correctly from what you have described above. If you provide a bit more detail, I can probably get you started in the right direction

Comment: I added the buttons code above that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this case delegation is a good choice, basically you will need a delegate object in your footer view. Then you set the delegate to TabBarController at runtime. 
When user clicks the button, call you delegate with your method `[delegate method]`

This is a very important design pattern objective-c, it would be very helpful if you can follow this tutorial to fully understand delegation.

http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002

Answer (score 0):

I agree that delegation is important and very much worth learning, but another way to solve the same problem would be to the following:

In your method definition for btnClicked, call the following code

```
if([self tabBarController]) {
     [[self tabBarController] methodToCall];
}
```

Since your view controller should be embedded within a tab bar controller, it will have this property set. You can then call any public methods contained within the tabBarController class.